# Apply function to appended jQuery element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` with such content:

```
<div class="foobar">Red</div>
<div class="foobar">Yellow</div>
<div class="foobar">Cyan</div>
<div class="foobar">Luke Skywalker</div>
<div id="data"></div>
```

I use this jQuery function to replace text inside the divs. After all I append 2 more `.foobar` divs to `#data`:

```
$(function() {
    $(".foobar").each(function() {
        $(this).html("Black");
    });
    appendDiv();
});

function appendDiv() {
    $("#data").append("<div class='foobar'>White</div>");
    $("#data").append("<div class='foobar'>Orange</div>");
}
```

And here I don't know how to apply inited `.each` function to appended divs. I've tried that, but it didn't worked for me:

```
$("#data").on("load", ".foobar", function(){
    $(this).html("Black");
});
```

How to apply `.each` function to appended html?

Comment: 6 `.foobar` divs with "Black" expression in each of them

Comment: @HenryDev and if I call `appendDiv` again, it should be 8 `.foobar` divs with "Black" in them

Comment: if you append first then run for each you got 6 `.foobar` updated to `Black`? check my answer...

Comment: If you're appending the HTML why not just set the values to `Black` when you append? The question makes no sense. Also note that your `each()` loop is redundant. You can just do `$('.foobar').html('Black');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function appendDiv() {
  $("#data").append("<div class='foobar'>White</div>");
  $("#data").append("<div class='foobar'>Orange</div>");
}


$("#data").on("click", function() {
  appendDiv();
  $(".foobar").each(function() {
    $(this).html("Black");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foobar">Red</div>
<div class="foobar">Yellow</div>
<div class="foobar">Cyan</div>
<div class="foobar">Luke Skywalker</div>
<div id="data">[TEST click me]</div>
```

Comment: thank you man, but there shouldn't be a "click" event, it should be on load.

Comment: @MrJo load from where? or you mean on change?

Answer (score 0):

Store the result $(".foobar") in a variable or, use this expression again.

Comment: I guess there's another way to solve it without storing data in variables, what if instead of one word I'm appending a lot of data and calling appendDiv many times?

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
$(".foobar").each(function(index, el) {
    $("#data").append($(el).clone());
    console.log($("#data").html());
});
```

**Explanation**:
It loops through all the divs with class foobar and *clones* than append each to the data div.